# ANDROID change of API

Tags: android, api

I've been given the task to modify an Android app. It uses an API which is on the main server and right now I don't have access to it. In the source code I changed the URL of the API from

```
private static String URL = "https://website/App_API/index.php";
```

to

```
private static String URL = "http://localhost/App_API/index.php";
```

in order to make a few tests but after the change the application says that "No internet connection is available". Anyone who has any suggestions how to access the local API?

Comment: did you deployed services correctly at localhost or what???

Comment: change localhost with computer `ip`

Comment: What do you mean by localhost? where did you deploy the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using emulator, try this

```
private static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/App_API/index.php";
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer) is the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

to access the localhost you have to use ip instead ie

```
String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/App_API/index.php";
```

see [Network Address Space](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)