# Why "10.0.2.2" was not there with running "ifconfig"?

Tags: vagrant

As you know I use vagrant to manage one vm, when I login to the vm using `vagrant ssh`, the output shown that I was login from 10.0.2.2. So this IP was my host's IP . But why can not I see it with running ifconfig in my host? That confused me. (But I can found a record about 10.0.2.2 in the host route table)

Any clue will be appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**10.0.2.2** always points to the local host when you are running emulator or vm. So in virtual machine , it refers to the local host (127.0.0.1) as 10.0.2.2. That is the reason you can't see it in ifconfig in your host. 
You can find more info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer) thread.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed,  that's helpful.