# SocketException:Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = 10.0.2.2, port = 80

Tags: flutter, dart

Making a login screen in flutter when i tap the login it gives the error 'network is Unreachable'.

I have change the ip addresses "10.0.2.2" , "8.7.7.7" but doesn't work.

**Error :**

```
E/flutter (16082): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled 
Exception: SocketException: Connection failed 
(OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = 10.0.2.2, port = 80
```

---

**CODE :**

```
TextEditingController user=new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController pass=new TextEditingController();

Future<List> _login() async{
  final response = await http.post("http://127.0.0.1/my_store/login.php", body: {
    "username": user.text,
    "password": pass.text,
   
  });

  print(response.body);
  }
```

---

Comment: We need some code to be able to help you.

Comment: @MartinNiederl Should i provide the whole script ?

Comment: Depending on whether your device is running in an emulator or on an external device, the IP address for accessing the local server must be adjusted.

Here's a little explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732276/6513167

I don't know your setup, so I also don't know how to reach your local server.

Answer (score 12):

In my case **turning on the wifi** and making sure that it is **connected** solved the issue.[image]

Comment: Discovering this forced me to create the (long overdue) network and internet connectivity features for my app. Hopefully it won't catch me again!

Answer (score 7):

Turning OFF the Wi-fi on emulator helped me!

Comment: Worked for me, too. Thanks very much!
This was strange, because other API calls were working to prove valid internet connection but only one was failing.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using a physical device make sure the ip address is the ip of your computer. you can find it by running `ipconfig` in cmd. Remember you have to be connected to the internet to have this ip address.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched some threads about this and similar connection problems. In my case, sometimes the connection works, sometimes it refuses to work. The process I used to solve this problem was the following:

**Open cmd -> ipconfig**

[the ip that is relevant for my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2FRh.png)

Since I am using an Apache server, and I have a php file that handles the request I make in Flutter, I set the url to the following:

```
 String url="http://192.168.0.137/login.php"
```

In your case, the code would be

```
    TextEditingController user=new TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController pass=new TextEditingController();

    Future<List> _login() async{
      final response = await http.post("http://<your_ipv4_of_ipconfig>/my_store/login.php", body: {
        "username": user.text,
        "password": pass.text,

      });

      print(response.body);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of head scratching, in my case it was the data connection icon was turned off by mistake cutting all sorts of data streams to vm :~