# I am using asp.net web api service in ionic. But its not getting service data in real device

Tags: asp.net, angular, web-services, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using angular Httpclient to call asp.net web api in ionic application all working fine its getting data from service in localhost:8200 but when it comes to real device the service response with error

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved: Basically you need to change the url on your project where you do service. Change it from `localhost:3000` to `10.0.2.2:3000`. The `3000`is the port's number, it doesn't need to be `3000`. Then you open android studio, open emulator and run it. On the litle tab right next to the android device, theres 3 dots at the end. Press those, then go to settings, and change proxy to `10.0.2.2` and the port number to the one you are using, in this case is `3000`. After that it will work. Sorry for late update on the problem! 
For more info: 
[why do we use 10.0.2.2 to connect to local web server instead of using computer ip address in android client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer)
If you are behind a proxy, download an APP called pulseSecure log in, and it should be good to go.