# React native Expo project, Fetch the API will get [TypeError: Network request failed], but the others api can work

Tags: react-native, expo, fetch-api

When I fetch the API in React native Expo project will get:

> **[TypeError: Network request failed].**

I have try to fetch other API, it can get data success.

And also try to fix by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639983/react-native-expo-fetch-throws-network-request-failed) but didn't work for me.
(Also tried this [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed))

Is API's problem?

**My code like:**

```
const val = { uId: 'molly', pwd: '123', id: '1' }
const url = 'https://c........com.tw:8899'

let header = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(val),
}
fetch(`${url}/auth/login`, header)
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((d) => {
        if (d.code === 0) {
            console.log(d.data)
        } else {
            console.log('MSG', d.msg)
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

And I have try this, it can work. (So is not the network problem.)

```
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((d) => {
            console.log('ok')
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Comment: this solution can solve your answer 
please go through it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed?rq=1

Comment: Sorry, I've tried this solution too. It didn't work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is about ssl.
Should use this package to deal with

```
react-native-ssl-pinning
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ssl-pinning