# React Native fetch() TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a react native app(Expo on IPhone) and an .NET Core 7 API as backend. When I try to send a post request to the backend using the react native fetch(I also tried with axios) an error is returned: TypeError: Network request failed. I tried to use the ip instead of localhost but the result is the same. The api respond to postman and swagger so the problem is no there.

```
fetch("https://localhost:7199/api/Auth/SendVerificationMessage", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                phoneNumber: "+40000000000",
                verificationCode: 0,
            }),
        })
            .then((response) => {
                // handle response
                console.log("yay" + response.status);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // handle error
                console.log("meh " + error);
            });
```

I also changed the Info.plist:

```
key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

After 1 day of searching I found the answer:
The problem is about a conflict between an emulator localhost and server localhost. Your back-end-server might be running on localhost:8000, but an emulator can't find this.

1. In cmd/terminal find your Ipv4-Address with a command 'ipconfig'. For ex., it will be 192.138.1.40
2. After this put it into your fetch ( 'http://192.138.1.40:8000/').
3. And what is also important - **run your back-end-server with the same host and port**. In VS you should go to launchSettings.json(or search by localhost) and there you should change the applicationUrl to using the ip instead of localhost.
4. Very important is that you should run the BE API on http not https

Many thanks to Anton Makarov which offered this solution on this post: [React Native / Expo : Fetch throws “Network request failed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639983/react-native-expo-fetch-throws-network-request-failed)

Comment: Just FYI, this solution worked for me. I only had to change the request using the IP address instead of localhost. I did not need to make any changes to the backend.