# HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data, uri = http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/images/0f61cb5dd19d38a11e5a9133333eca07.jpeg

Tags: flutter, api, networkimageview

when I'm using localhost then that problem occurs

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zKwmF7n1Sm13WMTmsyMCruLxmNGmXztF?usp=sharing

Comment: Does the image load when you open it in browser? I believe that url is local url right?

Comment: localhost(127.0.0.1) works fine for image load when I open it in the browser. but my base URL(10.0.2.2) is not working at image load when I open it in the browser. but In the Flutter app, this  URL(10.0.2.2) is working(print: Got Product) but also gets this error.

Comment: and what is 10.0.2.2 is? local phpmyadmin?

Comment: check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer

Answer (score 0):

Please check that image url again as its not loading in web browser also.

[image]

Comment: now check it out

Comment: is it localhost link ?

Comment: If you use 10.0.2.2 for connection it will always point to your localhost. 

The advantage of using 10.0.2.2 is that you don't care what is the real IP and you can move the project easier on another computer.