# connection failed while calling api in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, http

I am connecting api using swagger it is giving excelent result but when hitting api via mobile app it throws error
`connection failed: OS Error: Network is unreachable errorno= 101`

my api calling code

```
  var file = await File(filepath).readAsBytes();
  var uri = Uri.parse('http://192.168.18.2:1111/predict');
  // print(url);
  // Create a multipart request
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  // Create a multipart file
  var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'file',
    file,
    filename: filepath.split("/").last,
  );
  // Add the file to the request
  request.files.add(multipartFile);
  try{
    return await request.send();
  }
  catch(e){
    return http.StreamedResponse(Stream.error(e), 404);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to a number of issues.

- Make sure your device is connected,
- Wifi or data is enabled,
- your app has permissions,

and if you're using HTTP instead of HTTPS, on android and iOS you must [allow clear text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/975887) on Android 8 or higher.

Best place to start is to look at [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) while executing the code which will give an idea what is causing the failure. If you're connecting to local machine from an emulator, you also need to use the [10.0.2.2 address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer) instead.

If you're connecting on a local network from a real device to a PC, make sure you're in the same network, firewalls allow your connection .etc. as well.

Comment: actually my wifi was disable Thank you