# How can I find out what IP address to use to connect my phone to my React Native/Expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

So I read this post[why we use 10.0.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer) about how we use a different IP when we are using an android Emulator and I was wondering how can I find what IP should I sent in order to use the application on my mobile phone because right now my application is not working on my phone. It just sends network errors.

Comment: It depends on the OS you are using. It's different on windows, Linux and mac.

Comment: I am using windows