# Connecting Android Emulator with Wiremock Standalone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to set up a mock environment for my mobile app using Wiremock by running the standalone jar running on port 8080.

- The server is up, the files and mappings folders are created, and I have the mapping files which I can see when I hit `http://localhost:8080/__admin/`.
- AVD is launched, I have changed the proxy settings to add a proxy to `localhost:8080` and it shows success.
- The wifi setting on the emulator is also updated to use proxy as `localhost:8080`.

But as soon as I do that, I see an error '*Connected to device, can't provide internet*' and when I launch my app, it's neither able to connect to the internet nor I am seeing any requests being sent to Wiremock for matching.

I am stuck here and can't seem to find any solutions/documents to explain this connection process.

**Note**: the entire process is done black-box and not programmatically - that is, I am not trying to interact with Wiremock from my app code - Kotlin or Espresso.

Comment: You may need to proxy your emulator on your machine via `10.0.2.2` or your computer's network address instead of `localhost` -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732276/11625850

Comment: @agoff thank you! this solves the problem. Using `10.0.2.2` or local IP like `192.168.x.xxx` works!